# Defining a continuous map via homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $T_{2}$ space and there exists in $X$ a sequence $E_{1},E_{2},E_{3},...$ of closed disjoint homeomorphic copies of $X$. I am trying to define a continuous map $f$ from $X$ into $X$ such that $f|_{E_{i}}$ is a homeomorphism from $E_{i}$ onto $E_{i+1}$.

Let $f_{i}$ be a homeomorphism from $E_{i}$ onto $E_{i+1}.$ Define 
$f:X\rightarrow X$ by

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f_{i}(x) & \quad x \in E_{i} \\
            x & \quad x \notin \bigcup E_{i}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

But I am not able to show that $f$ is continuous. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

It may easily be not continuous. Just take $X = [-∞, ∞]$, $E_n = [n, n + \frac{1}{2}]$. $f_n: E_n \to E_{n + 1}$, $f_n(x) = x + 1$. Then your $f$ is not continuous at any $n$.